# How to generate a simple RSA key to encrypt a very short message?

Tags: cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt a message with RSA. I'd like to do this as part of a game/scavenger hunt I'm organizing for the holidays. I understand how RSA encryption works but I'm having trouble finding a way to encrypt and decrypt the message.

I found this site to help with encryption/decryption:

https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa11/notes/10.1_Cryptography/RSA_Express_EncryptDecrypt.html

but I can't seem to come up with any keys that make it easy to go back and forth for encryption/decryption of this message:

11-14-23-6 1-11 19 5-7-7-11-23

How can I come up with relatively simply keys to use? I know the purpose of RSA is to be difficult to crack but in this case it doesn't matter, I just don't want super long keys.

Comment: This could be helpful https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa11/notes/10.1_Cryptography/RSAWorksheetv4d.html

Comment: If you like my answer could you choose it as correct. @USB_Connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e   = 5

d   = 269

N   = 493

r   = 448

e*d = 1345

e*d mod r = 1

e and N are relatively prime,
d and N are relatively prime,
e and r are relatively prime,
d and r are relatively prime.

https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa11/notes/10.1_Cryptography/RSAWorksheetv4d.html